# Not getting reputation gains

Tags: support, community-wiki, specific-answer

I am not getting reputation gain for the last couple answer I posted, though it has two upvotes.  I am nowhere near any rep caps.  This particular question is listed as a community wiki but I didn't make it such and if it is, it shouldn't be. What gives?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998720/1085699

Comment: Link to the post?

Comment: you marked it CW (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21998720/revisions) - probably by mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to have been marked CW at the moment it was created (judging from the timestamps of both events).

This was probably done by mistake.

I have removed the CW from the answer, so any votes coming in from now on will be credited to you.

When posting new answer or editing one of your existing answers, beware the checkbox:

> [image]

Comment: what is the meaning of CW?

Comment: @Sam - [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)